# IIS using old dll in remoting. RemotingException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, dll

t appears as though my website is using an old dll during runtime, but compiles using the proper version of dll. I am running .Net 2.0 and IIS 6. I keep getting this exception:

```
"System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException": "The method \'ResumeEventProcessing\' was not found on the interface/type \'ITTRemoting.IAppServer, ITTRemoting, Version=1.0.5822.26723, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null\'."
```

It shows the correct version of my `ITTRemoting.dll`, but only can run older methods (added three new ones and I get this exception of all three, all other methods work fine).

I have restarted IIS, with no luck. I have checked `C:/Windows/assembly` to try to unload it. It was not there. I have restarted the server, with no luck. I have deleted all .Net2.0 `ITTRemoting.dll` temporary files, with no luck.

I had this same problem earlier this week, but it seemed to have worked itself out by magic which does not help me now. Please help.

Comment: maybe aspnet_regiis -i?

Comment: Didn't work.  Same error persists.